# Selenium WebDriver and java Can't find element & implicit wait problems

Tags: java, selenium

I've been trying to write a Selenium script in Java that will fill out an 'button' field on a web site

I'm trying to find this element

```
<div class="T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3 T-I-JW T-I-JO" role="button" tabindex="0" style="-moz-user-select: none;" gh="cm">REDACTAR</div>
```

First I go to the page, then I wait for a few seconds before I try to find the element but it doesnt works, it keeps telling me:`"org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element"`

---

this is the line

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=':3e']/div/div")).click();
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Answer (score -1):

Mr.Edward, I have an answer for this question. `Implicit` wait is used only for `FindElement()` ok?....and also `Explicit` wait is used only for some methods like `getText()` and all. if we are not able find these waits() then concepts comes Annotations,This is the best way to locate the Element, Please go through some of the Annotation tutorials,then also if you find any queries pls revert me back.